# array_flip() and utf8

Tags: php, arrays, utf-8, transliteration

I have an array (18 keys):

```
$en = array(
    'Ą' => 'A',
    'Č' => 'C',
    'Ę' => 'E',
    'Ė' => 'E',
    'Į' => 'I',
    'Š' => 'S',
    'Ų' => 'U',
    'Ū' => 'U',
    'Ž' => 'Z',
    'ą' => 'a',
    'č' => 'c',
    'ę' => 'e',
    'ė' => 'e',
    'į' => 'i',
    'š' => 's',
    'ų' => 'u',
    'ū' => 'u',
    'ž' => 'z',
);
```

those keys are lithuanian simbols (utf8 encoding).
When I do `$lt = array_flip($en);` it returns the following:

```
Array
(
    [A] => Ą
    [C] => Č
    [E] => Ė
    [I] => Į
    [S] => Š
    [U] => Ū
    [Z] => Ž
    [a] => ą
    [c] => č
    [e] => ė
    [i] => į
    [s] => š
    [u] => ū
    [z] => ž
)
```

as you can see 4 keys are missing ('Ę', 'Ų', 'ę', 'ų'). Whats going on here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nothing to do with UTF-8 here; just simple array/hashtable mechanics.

These keys:

```
'Ę' => 'E',
'Ė' => 'E',

'Ų' => 'U',
'Ū' => 'U',

'ę' => 'e',
'ė' => 'e',

'ų' => 'u',
'ū' => 'u',
```

Correspond to identical values in pairs. When you flip your array, the next of each pair overrides the previous, because you can't have two same keys in a single array. Hence the result:

```
[E] => Ė

[U] => Ū

[e] => ė

[u] => ū
```

If you need to map English letters to Lithuanian letters like this you may have to write a custom function that places multiple Lithuanian letters in an array, corresponding to the same English letter key (or rather, value).

Comment: Damn, i need my morning cup of tea...that was sooo stupid of me. Thanks for opening my eyes :)